How could I put regions of time on Apple Calendar which are not “events”?
For example, every day there is a window of time for me to do a certain task (that I generally must do. It is a large window of time - 12 hours.
I would like my calendar to somehow reflect that this does not mean those twelve hours I blocked out are some task I actually must do during those twelve hours. The task itself takes one hour.
It would be cool if these time regions were more faded or translucent on the calendar to make it clear they are not actually events.
Is any similar strategy possible, or anything to similar effect?
